# Does Resharper helps with System Performance?

Tags: c#, .net, resharper

I am wondering if by following all the standards and rules from Resharper... will it help me to improve the performance of my code?

I am not talking about if I will be faster coding. I am talking about if the code that runs after applying all Resharper's recommendations will be  faster than my original code.

Is there any kind of applications that may detect performance issues after analyzing code?

Comment: Resharper will recommend coding guidelines to hopefully produce more concise code with a higher level of consistency. There is no guarantee the code will perform any better due to compiler optimizations that may already take place.

Comment: Use JetBrains other tools such as dotTrace and dotMemory to highlight performance hot spots.

Comment: Thank you for your comments!

Answer (score 7):

Some of Resharper's suggestions will help you to notice potentially-costly performance-impacting mistakes. For example, if you iterate over an `IEnumerable<>` multiple times, Resharper will warn you about that, and if your `IEnumerable<>` requires a round-trip to the database any time you enumerate over it, that could end up hurting performance noticeably.

However, that's not Resharper's purpose. I would never rely on Resharper to help you catch performance issues, or even assume that Resharper's suggestions never hurt performance.

In fact, I would never trust the performance-related suggestions of any tool that only analyzes your code. Such tools have no idea what your day-to-day data is going to look like. Any auto-detectable change that's guaranteed to improve performance while leaving your program correct could be done just as easily by the compiler, without affecting your code's readability.

Performance is a tricky beast, and you really need a healthy mix of common sense, load tests, and profiling metrics to help you know what will help, what will hurt, and what really doesn't matter. In my experience, 99% of the decisions we make concerning how to write code fall into the latter category, so it's best to focus on performance separately from the day-to-day clean code decisions that Resharper helps you with.

Comment: Thank you for your comments!